# How to get Laravel last inserted ID from Excel import sheet

Tags: php, laravel

I'm relatively new to Laravel (historically I've written all my PHP from scratch) just trying to learn the basics Laravel site creation before making a new real site.  Right now I have a multi-sheet excel file that I want to import and place the data into tables.  I followed [the Laravel Excel instructions](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/multiple-sheets.html) and I have this ChartImport.php file that works well exactly as written/expected.

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\Chart;
use App\Chart_count;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;

class ChartImport implements WithMultipleSheets
{

    public function sheets(): array
    {
        return [
            0 => new ChartNameImport(),
            1 => new ChartCountImport(),
        ];
    }
}

class ChartNameImport implements ToModel
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Chart([
            'title' => $row[0],
            'owner_id' => auth()->id()
        ]);
    }
}


class ChartCountImport implements ToModel
{
    /**
    * @param array $row
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
    */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Chart_count([
            'chart_id' => 3,
            'count' => $row[0],
            'name' => $row[1],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Though right now, as you can see, I'm hardcoding

```
            'chart_id' => 3
```

I want the chart_id to be the automatically created id of the previous function call, but I'm not sure if there's any Laravel way to go about it.  I'm sure I could probably create a new PDO instance and grab the data from the database or something, but that doesn't seem like a good way at all.  How would you go about doing it?  Thanks!

Comment: Laravel Excel doesn't support relations if is this that you're looking for... if you look at the [repositories issues](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=relations) there are a lot of people asking for this feature

Comment: @IlGala don't think that's what I'm looking for.  I'm importing an Excel file with two sheets that goes into two tables.  I can do that much ok, but the I want the second table to have a column with a foreign key pointing to the newly created ID that was made in the first table when the row was added.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing to models you can import to [collections](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/collection.html#importing-to-collections):

example:

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

class UsersImport implements ToCollection
{
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) 
        {
            $id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId([
                'title' => $row[0],
                'owner_id' => auth()->id()
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

notice i am using the `[insertGetId]` [method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#inserts) to insert a record and then retrieve the ID.

Comment: Hi Dov, I'm not sure in your example how to specify which row goes with which column and how to pass the $id to the other function for it to be placed in the table.  It could be my own lack  of experience having never worked with collections before.

Comment: Hi Dan, Laravel Collections (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections ) are PHP arrays with superpowers ;-)

I have updated my example above to show that you can use it same as array.

Regarding passing it to the second import Just pass the **last id** through the constructor of the import object. It's just a PHP object, you can do anything with it that you would do with normal PHP objects.